# How to close element on second click? Using event click

Tags: javascript, html

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make a list with headings and on click at one it will show up a little description about the heading.

So far it only opens but it doesn't close. I tried to manipulate classes with if statements as well as I was searching for a solution but without success.

js:

```
export default function openTitle() {
  const colTitle = document.querySelectorAll('.col-title');
  const colContainer = document.querySelector('.col-container');
  const colContent = document.querySelectorAll('.col-content');

  colContainer.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    const clicked = e.target.closest('.col-title');

    if (!clicked) return;

    document.querySelector(
      `.operations__content--${clicked.dataset.tab}`
    ).style.display = 'block';
    
  });
}
```

html:

```
<div class="col-container">
            <div class="col">
              <div class="col-title" data-tab="1">
                <h3>Lorem</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-content operations__content--1">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt.
                  Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit
                  exercitationem.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="col-title" data-tab="2">
                <h3>Lorem</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-content operations__content--2">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt.
                  Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit
                  exercitationem.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="col-title" data-tab="3">
                <h3>Lorem</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-content operations__content--3">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt.
                  Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit
                  exercitationem.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
              <div class="col-title" data-tab="4">
                <h3>Lorem</h3>
                <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="col-content operations__content--4">
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt.
                  Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit
                  exercitationem.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Your script always sets the styling `display` to `block` or returns without doing anything, how do you expect to hide anything? You'd need to check if that div has a `display` of `block` and set it to `none` and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CSS class and use the `classList` API to toggle it:

```
element.classList.toggle('hidden')
```

```js
function openTitle() {
  const colContainer = document.querySelector('.col-container');

  colContainer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const clicked = e.target.closest('.col-title');

    if (!clicked) return;
    document.querySelector(
      `.operations__content--${clicked.dataset.tab}`
    ).classList.toggle('hidden');

  });
}
openTitle();
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-title" data-tab="1">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content operations__content--1 hidden">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt. Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit exercitationem.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-title" data-tab="2">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content operations__content--2 hidden">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt. Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit exercitationem.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-title" data-tab="3">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content operations__content--3 hidden">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt. Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit exercitationem.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col-title" data-tab="4">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-up"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="col-content operations__content--4 hidden">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ab asperiores placeat mollitia deserunt. Iusto quidem quas quia error quos nam sequi voluptas, architecto, nulla vel atque libero et suscipit exercitationem.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a  [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation) and `[element].classList.toggle` to toggle visibility.

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handle);

function handle(evt) {
  const origin = evt.target;
  const item = origin.closest("[data-item]");
  if (item) {
    item.querySelector(".txt").classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font: normal 12px/15px Lato, verdana, arial;
  margin: 2rem;
}

[data-item] {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.header {
   font-size: 1.3em;
   font-weight: bold;
   cursor: pointer;
}

.txt {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 0.3rem;
}

.txt.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div data-item>
 <div class="header">Header</div>
 <div class="txt">Lorem ipsem etc</div>
</div>

<div data-item>
 <div class="header"><i>Another</i> header </div>
 <div class="txt">Ipsem Lorem etc</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't use `Event.target` unless you really, really know what you're doing. Your entire suggestion will break as soon you add i.e: a simple `<b>` or `<span>` inside `.header`. I always repeat this and cannot stress out any more. Use always `Event.currentTarget` when possible, by muscle memory. Only when the currentTarget is not a feasible solution (in your exact example) **than use `.target` but always in combination with `.closest()`.**

Comment: Because of the event delegation `currentTarget` would always be `#document`, so not really usable. Edited the code a bit though.

Comment: I know, that's what I said. In your case the use of `Event.target` is correct. But incorrect because of not using `.closest()` *(before your edit)*. Just to repeat in short lines: Simple rule of thumbs: If we use `.target` but there's no `.closest()` - we might be doing something wrong.